# Encode accented characters from http request to email body

Tags: servlets, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

Good day.

I have a Java Tomcat's application the allow to compile a form where there is a textarea field.
The submit go to a servlet where the request fields are read and and e-mail to send is composed.
In order to send e-mail I use JavaMail.
The textarea field is inserted in the setText method of the MimeMessage class.
When I receive the e-mail in my client the accented characters are visbile as ? (question mark).
"Avrei bisogno di più informazione sull'immobile ed in particolare sulla sua qualità e ricevere delle foto."
"Avrei bisogno di pi? informazione sull'immobile ed in particolare sulla sua qualit? e ricevere delle foto."

Consider that the jsp page is UTF-8 econded and also the servlet processRequest start with request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Infact if I put the value in MySql table I haven't problems.

How can I resolve the problem?

Best regards.

Stefano Errani

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(your session);
msg.setContent(your content, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

I hope, it will help!